# multi2sim working with cuda sdk 5.5

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, simulator

I'm using cuda 5.5 sdk. When i compile anyprogram with this sdk especially nvcc, i can run on this on my gpu that is tesla m2090 fermi architecture. However i couldn't simulate this program with multi2sim because of version problem? now should i install old version or can i do something to solve this?

I got this error

```
fatal: __cudaRegisterFunction: The cubin has a unrecognized ABI version (0x7). Multi2Sim CUDA library is currently compatible with Fermi binary only.
```

Comment: Are you compiling for the Fermi architecture?

Comment: I think yes. i used sm_20. Should i do specific things to compiler for the Fermi architectures?

Comment: It's very likely an incompatibility with the type of code produced by cuda 5.5 and what multi2sim is expecting.  Do you have any reason to believe that multi2sim is certified to work with cuda 5.5? If your code doesn't depend on fermi features, you might try compiling with `-arch=sm_13` to see if there is any difference in the compatibility.

Comment: i'm still getting same error. I'll try with the cuda 4.0 sdk. I suppose i won't get same error. I'll write my result or if i find, solution :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [current multi2sim manual](http://www.multi2sim.org/files/multi2sim-v4.2-r357.pdf), p108:

> For compatibility with Multi2Sim, CUDA programs need to be compiled with the NVIDIA CUDA
>   compiler nvcc version 5.0.